# Why is my collections.sort leading to different outputs in 2 arraylists with the same data

Tags: java

I am having some trouble sorting 2 arraylists of mine which have the exact same data, one is received through my API and the other is parsed through ingame text fields, for some reason they are sorted differently even though they are the exact same.

```java
    public ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    AbowAPI api = new AbowAPI();

    @Override
    public void onStart() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            names = api.getTargets();
            Collections.sort(names);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onLoop() throws InterruptedException {
        if(tabs.getOpen() != Tab.FRIENDS) {
            tabs.open(Tab.FRIENDS);
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> friendList = getFriendNames();
            Collections.sort(friendList);
            log(friendList);
}
```

This here is the resulting output

```
[INFO][Bot #1][05/06 07:59:51 em]: [abc, abow42069, adam, bad, bl ack, blood, blue, bye, dead, dog, google, her, him, john wick, light, lol, mad, red]
[INFO][Bot #1][05/06 07:59:51 em]: [abc, abow42069, adam, bad, blood, blue, bl ack, bye, dog, google, her, him, john wick, light, lol, mad, red]
```

As I try comparing the 2 arraylists they are not also not equal, I need them to be sorted the same way so they match but I'm having troubles with it, any help to why they are sorting in different ways?

This is my API call to get the targets, maybe this is what is causing the weird bug?

```
enter code here
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/snipes");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.add(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return content;
```

Comment: content is not same e.g. `dead` is missing in second output. Moreover, I just used your data & getting identical result after applying sort.

Comment: removed that and now I attempt to sort them again, here's my result

`[INFO][Bot #1][05/06 08:47:42 em]: [abc, abow42069, adam, bad, blood, blue, bl ack, bye, dog, google, her, him, john wick, light, lol, mad, red]
[INFO][Bot #1][05/06 08:47:42 em]: [abc, abow42069, adam, bad, bl ack, blood, blue, bye, dog, google, her, him, john wick, light, lol, mad, red]`

you can see b lack and blood are in different positions

Comment: Even though logger is printing space there might be some special character in one `bl ack` or the other. And that is reason for arrangement.  Can you do any sort debug once sort is completed & check if content is really same

Comment: Any tips on how to debug?

Comment: you might see this for how to debug for your specific requirement : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqcJsKdjjvU&t=960s

Comment: You should get the element that is different from both lists and use `.equals`.

Comment: Also, you can look at the difference. What `getFriendsNames()` doing vs. `api.getTargets()` you're leaving out the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1):

The third character in "bl ack" is in one case a character that sorts before the lower-case alphabetics, and in the other case a character that sorts after them.

I would go with the hunch that says the first one is the "normal" space, and the second one is some other space (of which there are a few), and therefore the second one will have a character code greater than 127 - i.e., outside the usual ASCII range - which is possible since Java does not use ASCII.

To debug, I'd insert code like this:

```
for (String f : friendList)
    for (int k=0; k<f.length(); k++) {
        char c = f.charAt(k);
        if (c > 127) 
            System.out.printf("String '%s' char %d has code %d (%x)%n",
                              f, k, c, c);
    }
```

It's not pretty but it'll get the job done.  It'll work equally well if I'm wrong that the 'funny' character is a form of space, but is just something the logger is replacing by space. Armed with the character code in hex, you can look it up at [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

Replace 'printf' with anything more suitable to your development environment, if appropriate.

(For the purists, I'm guessing it's not going to be a surrogate pair, thus I'm using char rather than codepoint).

Once you know what you're dealing with, you can devise a handling strategy, which might be "replace the funny character with plain old space".

*Edited* since we now know the character is non-breaking space, 00a0 in hex.

You could, for example, change this:

```
ArrayList<String> friendList = getFriendNames();
Collections.sort(friendList);
```

to this:

```
ArrayList<String> friendList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> temp = getFriendNames();
for (String t : temp) {
    friendList.add(t.replaceAll("\\h", " "));
}
Collections.sort(friendList);
```

The `\h` represents any horizontal whitespace in a Java [regular expression Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), which includes the non-breaking space and others.  So we're going above and beyond the observed problem, normalizing all possible "spaces".

It would probably be better to make the same replacement in the `getFriendNames` method, but I don't think you've shown that code. Nevertheless, I hope you get the idea.

(Code typed in, not tested).

Comment: Could this problem possibly occur because of how I get the data from my API?
I will update my post to include it so you can check and see if I'm doing anything wrong

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Figure out what the character is and we can proceed from there.

Comment: Character for the targets "bl ack" the white space character in int value (i believe it's the unicode value, don't hate this is what I learnt in highschool haha) the white space character for that is 32 while for the friendlist one it's 160. Ah! Apparently that's the ASCII value, how would I go onto solving this issue then now that I know what ascii characters are causing this bug

Comment: 160 is U+00A0, which is a non-breaking space. I'll update my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: (Incidentally, don't say ASCII. That's an obsolete coding that has no character code greater than 127.  A 'char' in Java is a 16-bit value, and the encoding is Unicode. Yes, the first 127 codes in Unicode are identical to ASCII, but 'X' is still Unicode, not ASCII.)

Comment: @Abow "how would I go onto solving this issue then now that I know what ascii characters are causing this bug" What is an acceptable solution? You have a strange character in your data, how do you want to fix it? What's actually broken about it?

Comment: I suspect (but we have no evidence presented) that the name is originally typed with a regular space, and therefore something in the data path turns it into a non-breaking space. HTML in the path may well be responsible. On that basis, I chose the expedient solution of simply fixing up the aberration. But you (@matt) are correct in asking about the root cause.

Comment: @danglingelse I was pointing out that there isn't really a problem. They've asked a why question, and you've answered that. So what would make a solution?